# Implementing banker's rounding C++

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

So essentially I'm doing a C++ book, and one of the exercises is to modify an example from the book to use banker's rounding. For context, banker's rounding is where in fractional cents, you round to the nearest even integer. I've been trying for hours to find out how to implement it, but nothing has worked for me. The code from the book is listed below.

```
// Ex. 5.31: DollarAmount.h
// DollarAmount class gets two parameter constructor
#include <string>
#include <cmath>

class DollarAmount {
public:
    // initialize amount from an int64_t value
    explicit DollarAmount(int64_t dollars, int64_t cents) : amount{dollars * 100 + cents} { }

    // add right's amount to this object's amount
    void add(DollarAmount right) {
        // can access private data of other objects of the same class
        amount += right.amount;
    }

    // subtract right's amount from this object's amount
    void subtract(DollarAmount right) {
        // can access private data of other objects of the same class
        amount -= right.amount;
    }

    // divide amount by the divisor
    void divide(int divisor) {
        amount = (amount + divisor / 2) / divisor;
    }

    // uses integer arithmetic to calculate interest amount,
    // then calls add with the interest amount
    void addInterest(int rate, int divisor) {
        // create DollarAmount representing the interest
        DollarAmount interest {
            ((amount * rate + divisor / 2) / divisor) / 100, // dollars
            ((amount * rate + divisor / 2) / divisor) % 100 // cents
        };

        add(interest); // add interest to this object's amount
    }

    // return a string representation of a DollarAmount object
    std::string toString() const {
        std::string dollars{std::to_string(amount / 100)};
        std::string cents{std::to_string(std::abs(amount % 100))};
        return dollars + "." + (cents.size() == 1 ? "0" : "") + cents;
    }
private:
    int64_t amount{0}; // dollar amount in pennies
};
```

I've tried several things but I reverted the code back to its original form since the other ones didn't work. The current algorithm uses normal rounding. The author didn't really explain the rounding system very well.

Edit: Here's also the main program used.

```
// Ex. 5.31: Interest.cpp
// Compound-interest calculations with class DollarAmount and integers.
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include "DollarAmount.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
    DollarAmount d1{123, 45}; // $123.45
    DollarAmount d2{15, 76}; // $15.76

    cout << "After adding d2 (" << d2.toString() << ") into d1 ("
        << d1.toString() << "), d1 = ";
    d1.add(d2); // modifies object d1
    cout << d1.toString() << "\n";

    cout << "After subtracting d2 (" << d2.toString() << ") into d1 ("
        << d1.toString() << "), d1 = ";
    d1.subtract(d2); // modifies object d1
    cout << d1.toString() << "\n";

    cout << "After subtracting d1 (" << d2.toString() << ") from d2 ("
        << d2.toString() << "), d2 = ";
    d2.subtract(d1); // modifies object d2
    cout << d2.toString() << "\n";

    cout << "After dividing d1 (" << d1.toString() << ") by 2, d1 = ";
    d1.divide(2); // modifies object d1
    cout << d1.toString() << "\n\n";
    
    cout << "Enter integer interest rate and divisor. For example:\n"
        << "for     2%, enter:    2 100\n"
        << "for   2.3%, enter:   23 1000\n"
        << "for  2.37%, enter:  237 10000\n"
        << "for 2.375%, enter: 2375 100000\n";
    int rate; // whole-number interest rate
    int divisor; // divisor for rate
    cin >> rate >> divisor;

    DollarAmount balance{1000, 0}; // initial principal amount in pennies
    cout << "\nInitial balance: " << balance.toString() << endl;

    // display headers
    cout << "\nYear" << setw(20) << "Amount on deposit" << endl;

    // calculate amount on deposit for each of ten years
    for (unsigned int year{1}; year <= 10; year++) {
        // increase balance by rate % (i.e., rate / divisor)
        balance.addInterest(rate, divisor);

        // display the year and the amount
        cout << setw(4) << year << setw(20) << balance.toString() << endl;
    }
}
```

I'm currently testing with the inputs 2 100 and 5 1000000.

I've tried to make a conditional if the expression mod 1 is 0.5, and use the normal cents if it's true and uses the normal cents plus zero if the expression mod 2 is even and one if the expression mod 2 is odd. That ended up being messy and didn't even work and somehow got rid of all of the cents when I tested it. For the banker's rounding algorithm, inputting 2 100 should return 1218.98 for 10 years and 5 1000000 should always return 1000 because it's rounding to the nearest even integer, rounding down.

Edit 2: I've made some modifications to the code and I think I've thought of the algorithm I'll use. Here's the modified source code.

```
// Ex. 5.31: DollarAmount.h
// DollarAmount class gets two parameter constructor
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

class DollarAmount {
public:
    // initialize amount from an int64_t value
    explicit DollarAmount(int64_t dollars, int64_t cents) : amount{dollars * 100 + cents} { }

    // add right's amount to this object's amount
    void add(DollarAmount right) {
        // can access private data of other objects of the same class
        amount += right.amount;
    }

    // subtract right's amount from this object's amount
    void subtract(DollarAmount right) {
        // can access private data of other objects of the same class
        amount -= right.amount;
    }

    // divide amount by the divisor
    void divide(int divisor) {
        amount = (amount + divisor / 2) / divisor;
    }

    // uses integer arithmetic to calculate interest amount,
    // then calls add with the interest amount
    void addInterest(int rate, int divisor) {
        // create DollarAmount representing the interest
        DollarAmount interest {
            ((amount * rate + divisor / 2) / divisor) / 100, // dollars
            ((amount * rate + divisor / 2) / divisor) % 100 // cents
        };

        if (static_cast<int64_t>((((amount * rate + divisor / 2) / divisor) % 1) * 10) == 5) {
            if (interest.amount % 2 == 1) {
                interest.amount--;
            }
            
            std::cout << "test";
        }

        add(interest); // add interest to this object's amount
    }

    // return a string representation of a DollarAmount object
    std::string toString() const {
        std::string dollars{std::to_string(amount / 100)};
        std::string cents{std::to_string(std::abs(amount % 100))};
        return dollars + "." + (cents.size() == 1 ? "0" : "") + cents;
    }
private:
    int64_t amount{0}; // dollar amount in pennies
};
```

So essentially my plan is to just create the interest object normally, but then I check if the banker's rounding condition is met, and then if the interest.amount variable % 2 == 1, implying that it did not round to the nearest even integer. If this condition is met it deincrements the interest.amount variable. This seems to be a bit messy but since it doesn't seem like there is an easier way of doing it I think I'll be trying out this method. The problem is the if statement currently doesn't work that checks if banker's rounding is needed.

Edit 3: Added comments

```
// Ex. 5.31: DollarAmount.h
// DollarAmount class gets two parameter constructor
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

class DollarAmount {
public:
    // initialize amount from an int64_t value
    explicit DollarAmount(int64_t dollars, int64_t cents) : amount{dollars * 100 + cents} { }

    // add right's amount to this object's amount
    void add(DollarAmount right) {
        // can access private data of other objects of the same class
        amount += right.amount;
    }

    // subtract right's amount from this object's amount
    void subtract(DollarAmount right) {
        // can access private data of other objects of the same class
        amount -= right.amount;
    }

    // divide amount by the divisor
    void divide(int divisor) {
        amount = (amount + divisor / 2) / divisor;
    }

    // uses integer arithmetic to calculate interest amount,
    // then calls add with the interest amount
    void addInterest(int rate, int divisor) {
        // create DollarAmount representing the interest
        DollarAmount interest {
            ((amount * rate + divisor / 2) / divisor) / 100, // dollars
            ((amount * rate + divisor / 2) / divisor) % 100 // cents
        };

        // banker's rounding special case
        std::cout << (((amount * rate + divisor / 2) / divisor) % 1) * 10 << std::endl;
        if (static_cast<int64_t>((((amount * rate + divisor / 2) / divisor) % 1) * 10) == 5) {
            // if interest.amount is odd, implying normal rounding deviated from banker's rounding
            if (interest.amount % 2 == 1) {
                interest.amount--; // deincrement interest.amount to account for banker's rounding
            }

            std::cout << "test";
        }

        add(interest); // add interest to this object's amount
    }

    // return a string representation of a DollarAmount object
    std::string toString() const {
        std::string dollars{std::to_string(amount / 100)};
        std::string cents{std::to_string(std::abs(amount % 100))};
        return dollars + "." + (cents.size() == 1 ? "0" : "") + cents;
    }
private:
    int64_t amount{0}; // dollar amount in pennies
};
```

Edit 4: Okay, so I've figured out I will use normal rounding then check if bankers rounding is needed, then if it is and interest.amount is odd, implying it deviated from bankers rounding, it de-increments it. The only problem left is that my if statement that checks if bankers rounding is needed doesn't work.

Comment: It would be better if you could show us what you've tried, and we can help from there. Show us as well what inputs you tried, what results you get and what results you were expecting to get. Maybe you were close to the answer, but just giving you the answer won't help anyone.

Comment: Alright, I've went ahead and added what I've tried and the inputs I'm testing with. I've also included the main function which interacts with the class.

Comment: Calculate the product without dividing by `divisor`. Take the residue, say `r`, of the product modulo `divisor`. Compare `2*r` to `divisor`. If `2*r` is less than divisor, you will want to round down. If it equals the divisor, you will want to round to even. If it is greater than the divisor, you will want to round up. Then divide the product by `divisor` with truncation, producing a quotient `q`. If you are rounding down, do nothing. If you are rounding up, add 1. If you are rounding to even, add `q % 2` to `q`. (For example, if `q` is 3, the untruncated quotient was 3.5, so you want 4.)

Comment: (To support negative numbers, some modifications to that may be needed.)

Comment: Sorry, it's a little hard for me to interpret what you mean without an example of it in code. Since the exercise is asking me to modify an example from the book, I don't really understand some parts of the program that weren't explained very well, especially the rounding/truancy thing which the author hasn't explained very well. @EricPostpischil

Comment: Assuming the input value, is not an integral number of cents, "bankers rounding" will produce a value that is either greater than or less than the input.   So round up first.   If the result is an odd number of cents, decrement.

Comment: Well that's what I'm currently doing. The problem is checking if bankers rounding is required. For some reason my if statement isn't working. @Peter

Comment: Side note: [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Answer (score 0):

Here it goes:

```
// Ex. 5.31: DollarAmount.h
// DollarAmount class gets two parameter constructor
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

class DollarAmount {
public:
    // initialize amount from an int64_t value
    explicit DollarAmount(int64_t dollars, int64_t cents) : amount{dollars * 100 + cents} { }

    // add right's amount to this object's amount
    void add(DollarAmount right) {
        // can access private data of other objects of the same class
        amount += right.amount;
    }

    // subtract right's amount from this object's amount
    void subtract(DollarAmount right) {
        // can access private data of other objects of the same class
        amount -= right.amount;
    }

    // divide amount by the divisor
    void divide(int divisor) {
        amount = (amount + divisor / 2) / divisor;
    }

    // uses integer arithmetic to calculate interest amount,
    // then calls add with the interest amount
    void addInterest(int rate, int divisor) {
        // create DollarAmount representing the interest
        DollarAmount interest {
            ((amount * rate + divisor / 2) / divisor) / 100, // dollars
            ((amount * rate + divisor / 2) / divisor) % 100 // cents
        };

        add(interest); // add interest to this object's amount
    }

    // return a string representation of a DollarAmount object
    std::string toString() const {
        std::string dollars{std::to_string(amount / 100)};
        std::string cents{std::to_string(std::abs(amount % 100))};
        return dollars + "." + (cents.size() == 1 ? "0" : "") + cents;
    }

    void bankersRounding() {

        std::cout << "money: " << amount << " cents" << std::endl;
        int dollarsPart = amount/100;
        int penniesPart = amount%100;
        std::cout << " - dollars: " << dollarsPart << std::endl;
        std::cout << " - pennies: " << penniesPart << std::endl;

        // if it is equally distant from upper and lower integers,
        // then apply banker's rounding
        if (penniesPart==50)
        {
            // if the lower integer is zero, then round down to zero
            if(dollarsPart==0)
            {
                std::cout << "it is zero" << std::endl;
                amount -= 50;
            }
            // if the lower integer is even, then round down
            else if ((dollarsPart%2)==0)
            {
                std::cout << "even" << std::endl;
                amount -= 50;
            }
            // else the lower integer is odd, so round up
            else {
                std::cout << "odd" << std::endl;
                amount += 50;
            }
        }
    }
private:
    int64_t amount{0}; // dollar amount in pennies

};


int main()
{
    DollarAmount d1(0, 0);
    DollarAmount d2(0, 50);

    d1.add(d2);

    d1.bankersRounding();

    std::cout << "final: " << d1.toString() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, for the exercise the addInterest member function is supposed to be modified. Also, it's supposed to round fractional cents, not fractional dollars.

Comment: I noticed that it considers only cents, e.g. 1$ as 100 cents.

Comment: This implementation doesn't change the 'amount' member "to dollars". So it's still operating on cents,

Comment: I calculate dollarsPart and penniesPart just because it is easier for me to think like that, as it is more natural or typical of daily life. The implementation can be done in many other ways.

Comment: As 0 is even, there is a useless if in the code.

Comment: But the point of the banker's rounding system is to round pennies instead of dollars. For instance, 12.005 should round to 12.00 and 12.015 should round to 12.02, the closest even cent. It's not just supposed to operate on cents, it needs to operate on fractions of a cent.

Comment: I didn't remember that 0 is even thanks @Phil1970 :) ... I think that's a mathematical convention to not break the beauty of some well known algorithms.

Comment: I see @developer531, now I understand the required algorithm, far from what I did.

Comment: @developer531 I think that you will need to first rework how dollars and cents are handled, because with the current implementation, you cannot add fractions of cents, e.g. how can you define 12.005, when you have "DollarAmount(int64_t dollars, int64_t cents) : amount{dollars * 100 + cents} " ?
For instance 005 cents becomes 5 cents.

Comment: Well, I think I've figured out what I'll do. If you read the second edit, I've described my plan along with the current problem (the conditional that checks if rounding is needed). If you can find a solution for that conditional that would be helpful @JStark

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Here is my implementation of Banker's Round. I check the case that is `sth.5` and that it was rounded to an odd number to return something different. Lazy evaluation helps with performance but I ignore (and probably it is not) the most performant way to implement banker's round.

```
int bankersRound(double x) {
    double r;
    if(((x - std::floor(x)) == 0.5) && (std::fmod(std::round(x), 2.0) != 0)) {
        r = std::round(x) - 1.0;
    }
    else{
        r = std::round(x);
    }
    return (int)r;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Im not sure at which point youre stuck but maybe your are looking for something like this:

```
nearest_even=round(x/2)*2
```

I think thats a pretty simple implementation for "banker's rounding".

Comment: How that code will round 2.5 to 2 and 3.5 to 4?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: round(): Returns the integral value that is nearest to x, with halfway cases rounded away from zero (see: https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/round/).
So round(2.5/2) returns 1 multipled by 2 results in 2,
and round(3.5/2) returns 2 multipled by 2 results in 4.

Comment: @MaxHauptenbuchner But your code would give **incorrect result** for any number between 2.5 and 3.5 like 2.6.  would give 2 instead of 3 or 3.1 would give 4 instead of 3...